# "implicit declaration of function" in utarray.h (part of uthash)

Tags: c, gcc, uthash

I'm using utarray (part of the [uthash library](https://github.com/troydhanson/uthash)) for a project. Whenever I include it, I get the following error:

```
utarray.h:221:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Admittedly, I use some pretty aggressive flags when compiling (`-Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -std=c99`), but I don't understand why this should be an error at all. `strdup` is defined in `string.h` (according to `man strdup`) which is very clearly included from `utarray.h`.

What am I doing wrong? Google was no help. (apparently nobody else tries to compile `utarray.h` with these flags?)

Here's an example file that fails to compile (using `gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -std=c99 scratch.c`).

```c
#include "utarray.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    return 0;
}
```

versions: gcc 4.9.2, glibc 2.21, uthash 1.9.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`strdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) is not a c standard function it's a [**POSIX**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) function, you can't use `-std=c99` when you use `strdup()` unless you add the following `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` to the compilation command

```
gcc -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L
```

Comment: Even after including `string.h`?

Comment: Of course, that's possible. You just have to define the correct feature test macro (`-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L`). See the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html).

Comment: It's not quite correct to say `strdup()` is not a standard function.  It's not standardized by C99, but it *is* standardized by POSIX.

Comment: Note that there are other feature test macros that will also result in `strdup()` being defined by `string.h`.  In fact, the Linux/GLIBC manpage doesn't even mention `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, but rather `_SVID_SOURCE` or `_BSD_SOURCE`, or `_XOPEN_SOURCE` >= 500.

Comment: @JohnBollinger lately when compiling KDE, i've noticed that they use `_BSD_SOURCE` and **glibc** was complaining about it via `#warning`, and suggesting `_XOPEN_SOURCE`.

Comment: Is there one of those that is preferable? It seems like they each enable a somewhat arbitrary collection of functionality.

Comment: @DuncanTownsend actually it seems from it's name like `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is the best option, atlhough according to the manual it works since **glibc-2.12**, which doesn't matter if you are using another c library. For **glibc-2.10** and before it was `_GNU_SOURCE`, if you are using a build system, let it test which one to use when configuring the source.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with `strdup)`, so I added the dummy prototype statement

```
char * strdup(char *) ;
```

I don’t get the error message anymore.